# Find (ab) if $ \int \frac{15x^2dx}{\sqrt{2x-1}}=\left(ax^2\:+bx\:+b\right)\sqrt{2x-1}+C $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\int \frac{15x^2dx}{\sqrt{2x-1}}=\left(ax^2\:+bx\:+b\right)\sqrt{2x-1}+C
$$
What is the answer written as integer 
$$
225\sqrt{2x-1}+C
$$

(excuse my English)

Comment: Have you tried to derive the right hand of this equality ? You must obtain the integrand

Comment: @Advanced Warfare $225\sqrt{2x-1}+C$ is your answer to the integral?

Comment: yes, but how do I write it as integer?

Comment: @Advanced Warfare The integral is wrong. Do it again.  Hint: make the substitution $u=\sqrt{2x-1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int{\frac{15 x^{2}}{\sqrt{2 x-1}} dx} &=& \left(2+2 x+ 3 x^{2} \right) \sqrt{2 x -1} + C
\end{eqnarray*}
which means, $a=3, b=2$ and hence $ab=6$. Is this that you are seeking here?

Note: $y^{2} = 2 x-1$, which means $2 y d y = 2 dx $ or $ \frac{dx}{y}=dy$. The problem then translates to,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int{\frac{15 x^{2}}{\sqrt{2 x-1}} dx} &=& \int{15 \left(\frac{y^{2}+1}{2} \right)^{2} dy} \\
&=& \frac{y}{4} \left(15+10 y^{2}+ 3 y^{4}\right)  +C\\
&=& \frac{\sqrt{2 x -1} }{4} \left(8+8 x+ 12 x^{2} \right) + C \\
&=&\left(2+2 x+ 3 x^{2} \right) \sqrt{2 x -1} + C
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: yes, exactly, THANKS !

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate both sides (just as @popi commented) to get
$$\frac{15x^2}{\sqrt{2x-1}}=\frac{5 a x^2+ (3 b-2 a)x}{\sqrt{2x-1}}$$ Compare the coefficients to get $a$ and then $b$ and then the value of any $f(a,b)$.